# UIScrollView acting differently on iOS 5 and 6

Tags: ios, ios5, ios6, uiscrollview

I have a simple uitableview controller to start my application. I set it up so that there is a segue between this and the next controller. This next controller is a uiviewcontroller containing a uiscrollview all set up on a storyboard.

In iOS 6 this works perfectly but when I try to run on iOS 5 the controller with the scrollview decides to automatically scroll part way down the view. Any ideas what could be the issue? I do all the set up in the storyboard so I don't think I have any relevant code to share.

Thanks!

Comment: How about setting the content offset in `-viewDidAppear`, `-viewDidLoad`, or somewhere else appropriate for your app?

Comment: Most of the time, on IOS5 tableView and ScrollView doesn't go together. If i get you right, you have a table view at first and on action the scrollview loads. If that is the case you should keep in mind the navigation bar's size (i.e 24px from top).
Post the code and i will try to see the problem.

Comment: sorry I may not have explained it well. I have a tableview which on selection segues to a uiviewcontroller containing a scrollview. I create this all through storyboards so there is no code I can possibly show.

Comment: If I set the contentoffset to CGPointZero in -viewDidAppear it will scroll to the top but the user sees this scrolling to the top which is not a good user experience. Anywhere else i put it (-viewDidLoad -viewWillAppear) has no effect

Comment: Check the all the views springs and struts, and it's possible that your view controller has the iPhone 5 screen on the storyboard and whe you run it on iOS 5(smaller screen) the autoresizing can generate this issue.

Comment: @danypata thanks but I am running iOS 5 and iOS 6 on the same size screen

Comment: I understand, but when you drag and drop a UIViewController to the storyboard the default size is for iPhone 5

Comment: @danypata yes I had changed that. Also it appears the iOS 5 offset is 400 px so it wouldn't be due to something like that